# CSS not working properly when run through Flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am using CMDER to create my webpage and I am trying to get my CSS to run properly for my pages but some parts of the CSS isn't working. For example my #mainPicture isn't displaying and my contentBox and also the background colors isn't working. This is my css file.

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: left;
font-family:"Adobe Garamond Pro Bold", Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 13px;
color: #061C37;
background: #014D5D url_for('static', filename='images/background.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
*
{
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 text-align:left;}

#page
{
  display: block; 
  height:auto;
  position: relative; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 800px;
}

.topNaviagationLink
{
text-align:center;
position:relative;
margin-top:30px;
font-size:16px;
margin-left:-10px;
width:121px;
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
float:left;
color:#CEEAEE;
font-family:"Adobe Garamond Pro Bold", Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}


.topNaviagationLink a
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#CDE2FC;
}

.topNaviagationLink a:hover
{
text-align:center;
border-bottom:none;
color:#0C61C9;
display: block;
width:121px;
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
background-image:url_for('static', filename='images/tab.png');

}

#mainPicture
{
width:670px;
height:345px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

#mainPicture
{
width:670px;
height:345px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

#mainPicture .picture
{
position:relative;
width:650px;
height:325px;
top:10px;
background-image:url_for('static', filename='images/hudson1.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin-left:10px;
}

#headerTitle
{
position:relative;
top:30px;
left:40px;
font-size:25px;
color:#061C37;
font-family:"Adobe Garamond Pro Bold", Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

#headerSubtext
{
position:relative;
top:30px;
left:50px;
font-size:14px;
color:#008CBA;
font-family:"Adobe Garamond Pro Bold", Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.contentBox
{
width:670px;
height:auto;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
margin-top:10px;
}

.contentBox .innerBox
{
position:relative;
width:650px;
height:auto;
top:10px;
margin-left:10px;
background-image:url(content_back.png)url_for('static', filename='images/content_back.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
padding-bottom:35px;
}

.contentTitle
{
font-size:19px;
margin-bottom:0px;
padding-top:18px;
margin-left:15px;
margin-top:15px;
}

.contentText
{
font-size:13px;
line-height:24px;
margin-left:13px;
margin-right:13px;
}

html, body {
text-align: center;
}
p {text-align: left;}

input[type=submit] {
background-color: white; 
color: black; 
border: 2px solid #008CBA;
padding: 16px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
font-family:"Adobe Garamond Pro Bold", Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
margin: 4px 2px;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
transition-duration: 0.4s;
cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
background-color: #061C37;
color: white;
}
```

My App

**webapp.py**

**Static folder**-- cssfolder --imagesfolder

**templates folder** -- index.html -- newyork.html

This is newyork.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>New York</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/theme.css') }}">
</head>
<div class="innerBox">
<h2>New York</h2>       
<div class="contentText"><p>
New York is a state in the northeastern United States, and is the 27th-most extensive, fourth-most populous, and seventh-most densely populated U.S. state. New York is bordered by New Jersey and Pennsylvania to the south and Connecticut, Massachusetts, and Vermont to the east. The state has a maritime border in the Atlantic Ocean with Rhode Island, east of Long Island, as well as an international border with the Canadian provinces of Quebec to the north and Ontario to the west and north. 
</p>
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/newyork1.jpg') }}" alt="New York" style="width:750px;height:350px;">
<p>
The state of New York, with an estimated 19.8 million residents in 2015, is often referred to as New York State to distinguish it from New York City, the state's most populous city and its economic hub. With an estimated population of 8.55 million in 2015, New York City is the most populous city in the United States and the premier gateway for legal immigration to the United States. The New York City Metropolitan Area is one of the most populous urban agglomerations in the world. New York City is a global city, exerting a significant impact upon commerce, finance, media, art, fashion, research, technology, education, and entertainment, its fast pace defining the term New York minute. 
</p></div> 
</div>
```

And this is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#newyorkbutton").click(function(){
$.get("/newyork", function(data, status){
$("#city").html(data);
});
});
});
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>A Blog ABout My Travels</title>
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static', filename='css/theme.css') }}">
</head>

<body>

<div id="mainPicture">
    <div class="picture">
        <div id="headerTitle">Places I've Been</div>
        <div id="headerSubtext">A Blog About My Travels</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page">
    <input type="submit" name="NewYork" id="newyorkbutton" value="New York">
</div>
    <div id="city" class="contentBox">
    <div class="innerBox">
        <h2>Welcome to My Travels</h2>
      <div class="contentText"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p><br />
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></div>        
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It brings in the newyork template fine but it doesn't come up within the content box. The buttons also display perfectly its just the issues I mentioned at the top of the question.

Any help would be great.

Comment: The `url_for()` function won't work in your CSS file because it is not being rendered by Jinja. Replace those with the relative path and it should work.

Comment: The css file is not a template. You can't use template semantics like {{ }} or functions like url_for in it. It is simply included verbatim by the browser when the generated HTML arrives there.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. The CSS URL in the HTML file is not a file on the servers URL database. If you are using flask add this code to your `flask.py` file.

```
@app.route('/css/<file>') # the route name, <file> is like a request.args
def css():
  return render_template(file) # the file variable is created
                               # when a the <file> is something.
```

Then put your CSS files in your templates folder and put the filename in the HTML like so, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/file.css">`

You can do the same with any other file type.